# How Do I Open/Run A Class From A Separate Class?

Tags: c#, class

I'm making a simple DOS OS with C# on Xamarin Studio. The thing is I've made several programs doing just the thing I can't do on Xamarin, in Visual Studio.

As best as I can explain my difficulties: I have a class named `OSBootup.cs`, I want this class to run, then it starts a different class in my project. Is there any way to do that? And if not, what is another way I can do it?

My code: (OSBootup.cs)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace OperatingSystemCore
{
    public static class OSBootup
    {
        public static void Main (String[] args)
        {
            bool isStarting;

            Start:

            isStarting = true;

            Console.Write ("Starting SyteraOS ");

            Thread.Sleep (1000);
            Console.Write (". ");

            Thread.Sleep (1000);
            Console.Write (". ");

            Thread.Sleep (1000);
            Console.Write (". ");

            Thread.Sleep (1000);
            Console.Clear ();
            Console.Write ("Starting SyteraOS ");

            Thread.Sleep (1000);
            Console.Write (". ");

            Thread.Sleep (1000);
            Console.Write (". ");

            Thread.Sleep (1000);
            Console.Write (". ");

            Thread.Sleep (4500);
            Console.Clear ();

            Console.WriteLine ("Press Any Key To Start SyteraOS ...");
            Console.ReadKey ();

            End:

            DOSConsole DConsole = new DOSConsole ();

            isStarting = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And just in case you need to see my other file, (DOSConsole.cs):

```
using System;

namespace OperatingSystemCore
{
    public class DOSConsole
    {
        public void Start ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Give us a name.");
            Console.WriteLine ("");
            Console.Write ("Name: ");
            string Name = Console.ReadLine ();

            Console.Clear ();
            Console.Write ("User->" + Name);
        }

        public void Update ()
        {

        }

        public void Commands ()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `DOSConsole DConsole = new DOSConsole ();`, but you are missing `DConsole.Start()`

Comment: @mbeckish That's probably it, my Xamarin doesn't show all the functions I can do sometimes. It's pretty bug-filled. Thanks.

Comment: I love how back then, when I posted this, I was wondering if there was no way to open a seperate class. x'D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `DOSConsole DConsole = new DOSConsole ();`, but you are missing `DConsole.Start();.`

(This was answered by: mbeckish)